# Value of DTO field if is PrimaryKey autoincrement

Tags: android, kotlin, primary-key, android-room

In my Room Database in my application i have a table called Messages like below.

```
@Entity(tableName = "messages")
data class MessageDto(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "client_message_id")
    var clientMessageId: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "message_id")
    var messageId: Long = 0L,

    @TypeConverters(EncryptString.Converter::class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "body", defaultValue = "")
    var body: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "msg_type")
    var msgType: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "message_date", defaultValue = "")
    var messageDate: String,

    .........

)
```

So lets say that i want to insert a new message to the Database. I create a MessageDto object and then i insert it.

```
val messageDto = MessageDto(
                newClientMessageId,
                item.messageId,
                item.body,
                item.msgType,
                item.msgDate
                ...)

messageDao.insert(messageDto)
```

1) Since the PK exists only in the local Database i have to declare it mySelf. But since its autoIncrement what value should i put in?

2) The column body i want to be encrypted with a function that i have created. Is it right the way i have the TypeConverters?

Answer (score 1):

When a PK is autogenerated, you do not need to set its value. You can just insert your entity without setting the pk, the database will generate it for you and you can also retrieve the generated PK through the DAO. For example, given you have a MessageDao, you'll have this method inside it:

```
@Insert
fun insertMessage(message: Message): Long
```

and the returned long is your generated PK.

About the type converter: converters are thought to be used with complex data types, such as Date, and they should transform on object from a type to an other one. In your case, I get it you are transforming a String into an other String. That couldn't work with type converters, but you could encrypt your string before setting it in your entity. For example, if you are using a clean architecture, the repository would call a db data source, and the db data source would be the one delegated to encrypt and decrypt your field.

Comment: About converters i understood. Thnx.
However about the dto when i make that Dto what value should i put to that field? Because i must put something cos it gives me an error. I cant ignore the field....

Comment: if it requires a value, then you can use 0 (zero). that way, Room will know you're delegating the creation of the value to the db

Comment: If i want to insert a message and get the Long so i can add it to a column of another table object which i want to insert it also i have to make the insert(message) suspended?

Comment: I will make a new question. Thanks